# RSA-2048 bit in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, rsa

I was reading about RSA algorithm and how it works. I wonder how it calculates the 2048th bit .It is taking two prime numbers p and q, so what will be my numbers that will end with 2048bit encryption?

For Example:

```
Choose two distinct prime numbers, such as

    p = 61 and q = 53

Compute n = pq giving

    n = 61*53 = 3233

Compute the totient of the product as φ(n) = (p − 1)(q − 1) giving

    phi(3233) = (61 - 1)(53 - 1) = 3120

Choose any number 1 < e < 3120 that is coprime to 3120. Choosing a prime number for e leaves us only to check that e is not a divisor of 3120.

    Let e = 17

Compute d, the modular multiplicative inverse of e (mod φ(n)) yielding,

    d = 2753
    Worked example for the modular multiplicative inverse:
    (d * e) mod phi(n) = 1
    2753 * 17 mod 3120 = 1
```

The public key is (n = 3233, e = 17). For a padded plaintext message m, the encryption function is:

```
c(m) = m power 17 mod 3233
```

The private key is (d = 2753). For an encrypted ciphertext c, the decryption function is:

```
m(c) = c power 2753 mod 3233
```

For instance, in order to encrypt m = 65, we calculate:

```
c = 65 power 17   mod  3233 = 2790
```

To decrypt c = 2790, we calculate:

```
m = 2790 power 2753 mod 3233 = 65
```

I would like to calculate it for 2048. Can any one help me out to derive that algorithm for 2048?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

2048 refers to the bit length of the key which means that for the public key in a 2048-bit example, the big number, n, would be between *2<sup>2047</sup>* and *2<sup>2048</sup>*

The maths involved is the same as in an example with a smaller key

Comment: @thanks Cameron but can you explain it bit with example as I stated above with p n 1 values ? if I took p as 50 and q 43

n = (50-1)*(43-1) ; 49*42 = 2058

Comment: No, you can't really explain it with an example because the numbers involved are so massive we're talking about numbers with over 500 digits in them. It seems like you're misunderstanding "2048", "2048" is not the key, that's the size of the key in bits. Like I said, we're looking at numbers which are in the order of 2 to the power of 2047

Comment: Actually, the modulus is expected to be between 2^2047.5 and 2^2048

Comment: @Cameron I got it , can you just make me little bit clear on choosing e,d . when I got n value let say 3016 . so how do I know the e which should be a prime number not divisible by n and d should be a co prime of e.

Comment: 1: Find Euler's totient of n: φ(3016) = 1344. 2:choose e, it's up to you, lets use 17 again. 3:Calculate d = 1265 4: Check that (d * e) mod φ(n) = 1 for this example that would be 1265*17 mod 1344 = 1. In terms of the maths involved to calculate φ(n) and the modular multiplicative inverse of a number, there are many explanations of the methods to do this online and online calculators too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function
and for the modular multiplicative inverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse